# How to catch "Member not found in conversation?"

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'll begin with a brief overview of our architecture... we have a middleware server sitting between our client instances and Microsoft's Bot API. It supports things like looking up information in our client instances and performing certain actions on behalf of our clients, etc. One of the things we attempt to do is maintain a list of conversation users and keep this in sync between our middleware and the client instances. However, there is a "Member not found in conversation" error that is constantly being logged from the middleware when we call the `getConversationPagedMembers` method on the connector's conversations and we do not seem able to trap this error. In the last 30 days, we have had this error logged nearly 69,000 times.

The following is an example of the logged error. I have redacted any conversation and tenant IDs as well as our hostname with `[REDACTED]`:

```
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:29.983978Z 2024-01-31T15:49:29.984Z app:info Started GET "/users?payload=[REDACTED]“ for [REDACTED].uc.r.appspot.com at Wed Jan 31 2024 15:49:29 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:29.983978Z 2024-01-31T15:49:29.984Z app:info Started GET "/users?payload=[REDACTED]” for [REDACTED].uc.r.appspot.com at Wed Jan 31 2024 15:49:29 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411493Z 2024-01-31T15:49:30.410Z app:error [TID [REDACTED]] Error while getting users: RestError: Member not found in conversation.
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411517Z at new RestError (/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/dist/msRest.node.js:2479:28)
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411525Z at /layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/dist/msRest.node.js:3644:37
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411534Z at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411540Z at async /workspace/dist/server.js:1:166031
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411548Z at async /layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/p-timeout/index.js:50:13 {
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411560Z code: 'MemberNotFoundInConversation',
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411566Z statusCode: 400,
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411572Z request: WebResource {
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411579Z streamResponseBody: false,
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411590Z url: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/ca/v3/conversations/[REDACTED]/pagedmembers?pageSize=1000&continuationToken=',
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411596Z method: 'GET',
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411602Z headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411609Z body: undefined,
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411615Z query: undefined,
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411621Z formData: undefined,
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411627Z withCredentials: false,
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411634Z abortSignal: undefined,
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411640Z timeout: 0,
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411647Z onUploadProgress: undefined,
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411654Z onDownloadProgress: undefined,
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411660Z proxySettings: undefined,
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411666Z keepAlive: undefined,
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411672Z agentSettings: undefined,
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411678Z redirectLimit: undefined,
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411684Z operationSpec: {
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411691Z httpMethod: 'GET',
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411697Z path: 'v3/conversations/{conversationId}/pagedmembers',
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411704Z urlParameters: [Array],
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411711Z queryParameters: [Array],
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411717Z responses: [Object],
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411723Z serializer: [Serializer]
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411730Z }
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411736Z },
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411742Z response: {
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411750Z body: '{"error":{"code":"MemberNotFoundInConversation","message":"Member not found in conversation."}}',
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411757Z headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411763Z status: 400
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411769Z },
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411775Z body: undefined
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411782Z }
```

The status code appears to be 400 and the code seems like it should be `MemberNotFoundInConversation`:

```
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411560Z code: 'MemberNotFoundInConversation',
DEFAULT 2024-01-31T15:49:30.411566Z statusCode: 400,
```

The following two code samples are the methods in the middleware (JS running on node) that are called when one of our client instances attempts to fetch the linked users from the middleware. Depending on the number of linked users, this usually means multiple requests from the client instance to the middleware (and thus the middleware to the Bot API). For this, we pass a `continuationToken` parameter to continue through the paged results.

You'll note that we attempt to catch both `ConversationNotFound` and `MemberNotFoundInConversation` error codes with a `try-catch` in the `getConversationMembers` method:

```
async function getConversationMembers(
  connector: ConnectorClient,
  continuationToken: string | null,
  conversationId: string,
) {
  try {
    const options = {
      continuationToken: continuationToken || '',
      pageSize: 1000,
    }

    return await connector.conversations.getConversationPagedMembers(
      conversationId,
      options,
    )
  } catch (error) {
    if (hasKey(error, 'code')) {
      if (error.code === 'ConversationNotFound') {
        logDebug(
          `Ignoring conversation ID '${conversationId}'` +
            ' because it is no longer valid',
        )

        return {
          continuationToken: '',
          members: [],
        }
      }

      if (error.code === 'MemberNotFoundInConversation') {
        logDebug(
          `Ignoring conversation ID '${conversationId}'` +
            ' because the member was not found in the conversation',
        )

        return {
          continuationToken: '',
          members: [],
        }
      }
    }

    throw error
  }
}

interface Args {
  continuationToken: string | null
  conversationId: string
  serviceUrl: string
}

export default async function getUsers({
  continuationToken,
  conversationId,
  serviceUrl,
}: Args) {
  const responsePromise = getConversationMembers(
    createConnector(serviceUrl),
    continuationToken,
    conversationId,
  )

  const timeoutMs = 60 * 1000
  const response = await pTimeout(responsePromise, timeoutMs)

  return {
    continuationToken: response.continuationToken || '',
    users: convertToUsers(response.members),
  }
}
```

One thing to note is that the `pTimeout` library is used in order to timeout a hanging promise. I thought this might be worth mentioning since it seems like our logged error trace originates from that library.

What we'd like to be able to do is catch this error and return an empty `members` array to the calling client instance but we seem to be unable to do this. Any help or suggestions will be most appreciated!

Comment: Could please catch/return this empty member array before library timeout try block.